# AddOpenIdConnect in a WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application, openid-connect

So I need to `AddOpenIdConnect` in order to declare my `SignInScheme` and `Scopes`.

Any idea how to do this in a WPF App? And where should this method be called?

```
services.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; // cookie middle setup above
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000"; // Auth Server
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // only for development 
    options.ClientId = "native.code"; // client setup in Auth Server
    options.ResponseType = "token";
    options.Scope.Add("fiver_auth_api");
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
});
```

It`s my first time working with Desktops Apps.

Comment: Try finding a tutorial on creating WPF Applications like www.wpf-tutorial.com or the like. Integrating your method then is very simple, you can "connect" via button press etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this library and associated samples. Should give you everything you need:

https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient2

The recommended way to handle OIDC sign ins in a desktop app is to use the user's default browser and either a custom URL scheme or local HTTP listener to receive the response.